# random.shuffle is acting strange in list of lists made with list multiplication

Tags: python, list, random

My `createIndividual` function is trying to take a list of lists of lists called `courses`, and then add members of a global list variable (`PEOPLE`) to it randomly. The code is:

```
def createIndividual(courses):
    # Courses is equal to an individual, but
    # without people
    individual = courses.copy()
    for course in individual:
        myPeople = PEOPLE.copy()
        random.shuffle(myPeople)
        for table in course:
            while len(table) < table.maximum:
                table.append(myPeople.pop())
    return individual
```

I ran this function a bunch of times, trying to get lots of copies with different results. However, each time it created the exact same results for the `course` variable within each individual.

The results differed between runs of the program, but were the same within a single run.

An example value of the `courses` argument would be:

```
[[[], [], []],
 [[], [], []]]
```

The innermost "lists" are actually `Table()` classes, which have a `maximum` value defined, but in all other ways act like lists. The `maximum` attribute of each `Table` is 3.

The list of `PEOPLE` would be:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

The first `individual` created was:

```
[[[4, 3, 8], [5, 9, 2], [1, 6, 7]],
 [[4, 3, 8], [5, 9, 2], [1, 6, 7]]]
```

The second `individual` created was:

```
[[[9, 8, 3], [7, 2, 1], [6, 5, 4]],
 [[9, 8, 3], [7, 2, 1], [6, 5, 4]]]
```

These continue with apparent randomness, but each `course` in the `individual` is always identical to the other `course`s within the same `individual`, regardless of how I change the parameters.

Comment: Among other possible problems, you appear to be creating a shuffled copy of `PEOPLE`, and then using that one copy to fill a bunch of `table`s (lists?), without verifying you have enough people to do so.  If it ever runs out, `myPeople.pop()` will raise `IndexError: pop from empty list`.

Comment: Also, what exactly is passed as the argument to the `courses` parameter?  It _can't_ be a list of lists, because a `list` doesn't have a `copy` method.  (Also, I really don't understand what you mean by "`courses` is equal to an individual, but without people".

Comment: Lists don't have a `.maximum` either, come to think of it.  There's _no way_ `courses` or `table` are normal Python lists.  Please (re-)read how to create a "[mcve]", and then [edit] your post to include the information we need to answer it.

Comment: Sorry @KevinJ.Chase. I really appreciate your help- I haven't been on Stackoverflow long, still trying to learn how to ask well.

Comment: Looks like lists _do_ have `copy` methods in  recent versions of Python.  From [4.6.3. Mutable Sequence Types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types), note 5:  "_New in version 3.3_: `clear()` and `copy()` methods.".   I only had an older version of Python handy when I wrote that comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question really needs more detail to answer it with confidence, but since there's a common error that could produce this weird result (and since I wasn't able to reproduce it any other way)...

I think the problem is not in your `createIndividual` function, but in the data structure you're feeding it.  Here's a bit of my `main` function that produced exactly the random output you expected:

```python3
from pprint import pprint
# pprint is essential for pretty-printing deeply nested data.

class Table(object):
    ...
    # Guesswork on my part, plus a custom __str__ and __repr__.

def main():
    # This creates a list of two lists-of-three-Tables.
    distinct_courses = [[Table() for __ in range(3)] for __ in range(2)]

    filled_courses = createIndividual(distinct_courses)
    pprint(filled_courses)
```

Output:

```python3
[[Table([1, 2, 3]), Table([5, 8, 6]), Table([7, 4, 9])],
 [Table([7, 5, 3]), Table([2, 6, 8]), Table([9, 1, 4])]]
```

To reproduce your problem, I had to create `courses` using the list-multiplication syntax, which doesn't do what most beginners (and some tutorials) think it does:

> ### [4.6.1. Common Sequence Operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-common)
>
> [table omitted]
>
> Notes:
>
> 2. [...]  Note that items in the sequence *s* are not copied; they are referenced multiple times. This often haunts new Python programmers; [...]
>
> Further explanation is available in the FAQ entry [How do I create a multidimensional list?](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#faq-multidimensional-list).

I'm guessing somewhere in your code, you did something like this:

```python3
def bogus_main():
    # This creates a single lists-of-three-Tables...
    course = [Table() for __ in range(3)]
    # ...then creates a list of two references to the _same_ list.
    aliased_courses = [course] * 2

    filled_courses = createIndividual(aliased_courses)
    pprint(filled_courses)
```

Output using the aliased lists:

```python3
[[Table([7, 9, 2]), Table([8, 6, 1]), Table([5, 3, 4])],
 [Table([7, 9, 2]), Table([8, 6, 1]), Table([5, 3, 4])]]
```

Since both `courses[0]` and `courses[1]` point to the *same* list, two weird things happen.  First, the contents of the "two" `course`s will be the same, as you've already noticed.  Each update seems to add a pair of identical `Table`s to two different lists, although it's really just adding one `Table` to one list... and then printing that list twice...  You can see this in action by adding an extra `pprint` to `createIndividual`:

```python3
[[Table([]), Table([]), Table([])],
 [Table([]), Table([]), Table([])]]

[[Table([7, 9, 2]), Table([]), Table([])],
 [Table([7, 9, 2]), Table([]), Table([])]]

[[Table([7, 9, 2]), Table([8, 6, 1]), Table([])],
 [Table([7, 9, 2]), Table([8, 6, 1]), Table([])]]

[[Table([7, 9, 2]), Table([8, 6, 1]), Table([5, 3, 4])],
 [Table([7, 9, 2]), Table([8, 6, 1]), Table([5, 3, 4])]]

[[Table([7, 9, 2]), Table([8, 6, 1]), Table([5, 3, 4])],
 [Table([7, 9, 2]), Table([8, 6, 1]), Table([5, 3, 4])]]

[[Table([7, 9, 2]), Table([8, 6, 1]), Table([5, 3, 4])],
 [Table([7, 9, 2]), Table([8, 6, 1]), Table([5, 3, 4])]]

[[Table([7, 9, 2]), Table([8, 6, 1]), Table([5, 3, 4])],
 [Table([7, 9, 2]), Table([8, 6, 1]), Table([5, 3, 4])]]
```

Second, notice how the last three "updates" don't actually change anything?  Something *should* have failed when you tried to add 18 values to only 9 slots.  Unfortunately, the `maximum` field that protects you from over-filling a `Table` also saves you from the error that could have tipped you off earlier.  From `createIndividual`:

```python3
for table in course:
    while len(table) < table.maximum:
        # Once the "first" aliased course list is full, this will
        # never pop another person, because there's no place to
        # store them.
        table.append(myPeople.pop())
    print(len(myPeople))  # My addition.
    # Prints 6, 3, and 0 during the first `course`, then prints
    # 9, 9, and 9... myPeople never changes the second time through.
```

After the "first" (really, the only) three `Table`s are filled, they're all at `maximum` length, so neither `individual` or `myPeople` will change again.

Contrast the list-comprehension version in my `main`, which creates six different `Table` objects, like you'd expect:

```python3
[[Table([]), Table([]), Table([])],
 [Table([]), Table([]), Table([])]]

[[Table([1, 2, 3]), Table([]), Table([])],
 [Table([]), Table([]), Table([])]]

[[Table([1, 2, 3]), Table([5, 8, 6]), Table([])],
 [Table([]), Table([]), Table([])]]

[[Table([1, 2, 3]), Table([5, 8, 6]), Table([7, 4, 9])],
 [Table([]), Table([]), Table([])]]

[[Table([1, 2, 3]), Table([5, 8, 6]), Table([7, 4, 9])],
 [Table([7, 5, 3]), Table([]), Table([])]]

[[Table([1, 2, 3]), Table([5, 8, 6]), Table([7, 4, 9])],
 [Table([7, 5, 3]), Table([2, 6, 8]), Table([])]]

[[Table([1, 2, 3]), Table([5, 8, 6]), Table([7, 4, 9])],
 [Table([7, 5, 3]), Table([2, 6, 8]), Table([9, 1, 4])]]
```

Comment: Wow. This is exactly what I did. Thank you so much for your time and effort; I had no idea the problem could lie there. This is an amazing answer- and a great lesson on how list-multiplication syntax works. I kept seeing other people using it, and thought I'd try it. Thank you again so much!

Comment: @PaulBuga:  List multiplication is a shortcut that I really don't think is worth the confusion.  It can work if the list contains _only_ immutable values (meaning it can't contain another list, among other things), or if you _never_ alter it or anything it contains.  Also, there are a few occasions where you really do want lists of aliases... but not many.  I just avoid it.

Comment: Good to know. Thank you so much again!

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `deepcopy` because your lists store another lists and you have to copy them too. Look for examples: http://www.python-course.eu/deep_copy.php

Comment: Thanks! Never knew that could be an issue.

Comment: Well, I've changed the line 4 to be myPeople = deepcopy(PEOPLE), and line 2 to be individual = deepcopy(courses) and the same issue happens.

Comment: Show  code where `courses` and `PEOPLE` are defined.